# How to create a grep stdout in python and store it in a variable

Tags: python, bash, terminal, grep, stdout

I want to read a file using grep system command in python by running this grep command through python and store the stdout in a python variable. How is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: Why do you want to run grep in your Python script? Python has its own regex module, `re`, which is **much** more versatile than what you can do with grep. The regex syntax is similar, although Python doesn't support the character class shortcuts [:alnum:], [:alpha:], [:cntrl:], etc, but it does have equivalent syntax for the main ones.